# codeigniter form_dropdown, set option value without an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter

I want to fetch a table which has 2 columns: id and name,
and I want column id as value for each option, and column name as option name

This is my controller

```html
 //populate provinsi
        $this->load->model('Provinsi');
        $provinsi = $this->Provinsi->get();

        $this->load->view('admin/pages/product_form', array(
            'provinces' => $provinsi,
        ));
```

And in my view

```html
<?php
$options_provinsi = array('select_one' => 'Select one');
foreach ($provinces as $provinsi) {
       $options_provinsi[] = array(
              $provinsi->id => $provinsi->nama,
       );
}

$extra = 'id="provinsi" class="form-control" onChange="loadLocation('provinsi','kota');"';
echo form_dropdown('provinsi', $options_provinsi, 'select_one', $extra);
?>
```

This code meet my needs, but because I use array, the dropdown become like this:

[image: dropdown_error]

How to set option value without using an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your foreach loop

```
foreach ($provinces as $provinsi) {
       $options_provinsi[$provinsi->id] = $provinsi->nama;
}
```

and in view

```
$extra = null;
echo form_dropdown('provinsi', $options_provinsi, 'select_one', $extra);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put This :

```
$extra_string = null;
foreach($extra as $key => $value) {
     $extra_string .= " {$key}='{$value}'"; 
}
```

And change last line to be:

```
echo form_dropdown('provinsi', $options_provinsi, 'select_one', $extra_string);
```

As you can see checking [codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) docs you will find out that extra param should be string not an array.

- If it it's an array then form_dropdown() will produce an  with the array key as the label.

Comment: thanks to remind me about parameter $extra, but the problem come from $options_provinsi array.

Comment: Nope, your problem is because of $extra parameter in array type produces <optgroup> which leads to the picture you attached.

Comment: how if i change my $extra like in above?, is it the same with your example?

Comment: you are still getting same result after changing it to string?

Comment: yes, i even remove $extra parameter. like i said the problem comes from $options_provinsi. because i use nested array. do you know how to change my nested array to single array?